# How to install postgres and create new user and db using ansible playbook?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, ansible, ansible-playbook

I tried using below playbook to install postgres 12 on my ubuntu machine on both 22 and 23 versions of ubuntu. For installating postgres and set a default password to postgres user and create a new user and database after that.

```
---
- hosts: local
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  vars:
    postgresql_version: 12
    db_name: your_database
    db_user: your_user
    db_password: your_password
    postgres_password: your_postgres_password

  tasks:
    - name: Update apt cache
      apt: update_cache=yes

    - name: Add the PostgreSQL APT key
      apt_key:
        url: https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc
        state: present

    - name: Add the PostgreSQL APT repositories
      apt_repository:
        repo: deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ {{ ansible_distribution_release }}-pgdg main
        state: present

    - name: Update apt cache
      apt: update_cache=yes

    - name: Install PostgreSQL
      apt:
        name: postgresql-{{ postgresql_version }}
        state: present

    - name: Set password for the default PostgreSQL user
      become: yes
      become_user: postgres
      shell: 'psql -c "ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD ''{{ postgres_password }}'';"'

    - name: Create a new user in PostgreSQL
      become: yes
      become_user: postgres
      shell: 'psql -c "CREATE USER {{ db_user }} WITH PASSWORD ''{{ db_password }}'' SUPERUSER;"'

    - name: Create a new database in PostgreSQL
      become: yes
      become_user: postgres
      shell: 'psql -c "CREATE DATABASE {{ db_name }} WITH OWNER {{ db_user }};"'

    - name: Create a new database in PostgreSQL
      become: yes
      become_user: postgres
      command: 'psql -c "CREATE DATABASE {{ db_name }} WITH OWNER {{ db_user }};"'
```

But, getting below error

> TASK [Set password for the default PostgreSQL user]
> ******************************************************************** fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Failed to set permissions on
> the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an
> unprivileged user (rc: 1, err: chmod: invalid mode:
> ‘A+user:postgres:rx:allow’\nTry 'chmod --help' for more
> information.\n}). For information on working around this, see
> [https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-core/2.14/user_guide/become.html#risks-of-becoming-an-unprivileged-user"}](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-core/2.14/user_guide/become.html#risks-of-becoming-an-unprivileged-user%22%7D)
>
> PLAY RECAP
> ************************************************************************************************************* localhost                  : ok=6    changed=2    unreachable=0
> failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

How to fix that?

My inventory_file:

```
[local]
localhost ansible_connection=local
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read [in this link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-core/2.14/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html#playbooks-privilege-escalation) that:

> Ansible modules are executed on the remote machine by first substituting the parameters into the module file, then copying the file to the remote machine, and finally executing it there.

> Everything is fine if the module file is executed without using become, when the become_user is root, or when the connection to the remote machine is made as root. In these cases, Ansible creates the module file with permissions that only allow reading by the user and root, or only allow reading by the unprivileged user being switched to.

> However, when both the connection user and the become_user are unprivileged, the module file is written as the user that Ansible connects as (the remote_user), but the file needs to be readable by the user Ansible is set to become.

So, if you are using an ansible user without root privileges, when the module shell for changing the password is sent to the remote machine, the postgres user is unable to execute it appropriately.

An alternative is executing psql with a sudo (not execute the task, only the command):

```
- name: Set password for the default PostgreSQL user
  command: sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD '{{ postgres_password }}';"
```